# mongo object causes high cpu usage

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

When we deployed our java app using spring data + mongodb we noticed that the cpu spiked to 100%. After removing the mongo configuration it went back to normal. The application is literally doing nothing with mongo, we merely have it added to the context file

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? The cpu slowly gets eaten up until it reaches 150%.

Comment: Ca you create a reproducing test case for this? A sample Maven project maybe?

Comment: Hey oliver. The weird thing is, it only happens in a certain environment. Locally we are not able to reproduce it. We actually tried starting up a mongo server for the app to connect to and the cpu went down to 0% within seconds.